# How to define value of nested object at runtime in Autofac

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, autofac

Let's say I have the following hierarchy.

```
class PersonWithJacket
{
    public PersonWithJacket(Jacket jacket)
    {
    }
}

class Jacket
{
    public Jacket(string brand)
    {
    }
}
```

I register these classes in my Autofac container

```
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<PersonWithJacket>();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<Jacket>();
```

At runtime I want to resolve a `PersonWithJacket` object and I want to define the `string brand` constructor parameter of the nested `Jacket` class. My first approach was to use the `NamedParameter` like so:

```
        var personWithJacket = container.Resolve<PersonWithJacket>(new NamedParameter("brand", "TheBrand"));
```

I read that as "resolve the a `PersonWithJacket` object and if you encounter a constructor parameter called 'brand', use the value 'TheBrand'" but the string parameter cannot be resolved.

Is there a way to define, at runtime, the value of a constructor parameter of a nested object?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific with what you are trying to accomplish? Are you trying to pass in a `Jacket` to the `PersonWithJacket` ctor? Is `PersonWithJacket` supposed to inherit `Jacket`?

Comment: I basically want to get two different `PersonWithJacket` objects each with a different `Jacket`'s brand name. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: Oh, I see. I assume that these name brand `Jacket`s are registered with Autofac as well?

Comment: The Jacket is but it's names are not because they are only known at runtime.

Comment: Ah, I think I got it. Let me write it up.

Comment: Bah, doing it in a nice and clean way is a lot harder than I thought it would be. For now, you can simply resolve the `Jacket` first, and then pass that value into `Resolve<PersonWithJacket>(jacket)`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do it seems to be by using a container hierarchy. I create a base container where I register all the common types and instances and then create child containers that register the parts that vary.

```
var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
containerBuilder.RegisterType<PersonWithJacket>();

var childContainer1 = new MultitenantContainer(new NullTenantIdStrategy(), containerBuilder.Build());
childContainer1.ConfigureTenant(null, builder => builder.Register(context => new Jacket("Hugo Boss")));

var childContainer2 = new MultitenantContainer(new NullTenantIdStrategy(), containerBuilder.Build());
childContainer2.ConfigureTenant(null, builder => builder.Register(context => new Jacket("H&M")));

var personWithHugoBossJacket = childContainer1.Resolve<PersonWithJacket>();
var personWithHandMJacket = childContainer2.Resolve<PersonWithJacket>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, never mind. It's not that bad with `ResolvedParameter`s.

```
        using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope()) {
            var someDynamicString = "Brand B";

            var personDude = scope.Resolve<PersonWithJacket>(new ResolvedParameter(
                (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(Jacket),
                (pi, ctx) => ctx.Resolve<Jacket>(new NamedParameter("name", someDynamicString))));
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not flexible enough. I solved it with `MultitenantContainers`.